# blueimp does not allow second post operation via jquery adapter

Tags: php, jquery, blueimp

I am using blueimp in my website. blueimp is included at the end of my page(index.php) like:

```
 <?php include "index.html"; ?>
```

In my php page I am also using a jquery adapter which sends some variables from the same page and two variables from blueimp uploader via:

```
   function save()
     {  
    var variable1= document.getElementById('field1').value;
        var variable2= CKEDITOR.instances.field2.getData();
    variable2=encodeURIComponent(variable2);
    var variable3= document.getElementById('field3').value;
        var variables="variable1="+variable1+ "&variable2="+variable2+                                 
                      "&variable3="+variable3;


           jQuery('#mydiv').showLoading();
           $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "some.php",
                        data: variables,
                        error: function(){
                           alert('Error while loading!');
                         },
                       success: function(data){
              jQuery('#mydiv').hideLoading();
                          $('#mydiv').html(data);
                      }
                });
    }
```

Whenever I call this function the variables are not sent to some.php . However if I remove

```
       <?php include "index.html"; ?>
```

from index.php page, the function save starts to work. I guess something from included blueimp  page ,which is index.html, prevents the jquery adapter to function properly.

Is there any clue on this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are having some conflicts between the two libraries.  jQuery has [this](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) option called `noConflict()` to allow you to sort of 'pause' jQuery for a bit and allow other libraries to work and then 'resume' normal jQuery functions.

Comment: davehale thank you so much for your reply. Am I supposed to use it in my "save" function stated above? if yes could you please show me where exactly use it.

Comment: davehale , thank you so much again. I fixed the problem as you stated above. noConflict() worked.